# Parsing JSON with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am working on an app which fetches data from a server. I convert this data to XML and then parse it using XMLDictionary. My problem is counting the number of objects inside the dictionary.

```
"finance_fee_collection" =     (
            {
        amount = "790.00";
        "due_date" = "2015-06-04";
        name = "Third Payment";
    },
            {
        amount = "790.00";
        "due_date" = "2014-12-11";
        name = "First Payment";
    },
            {
        amount = "740.00";
        "due_date" = "2015-07-06";
        name = "third payment";
    }
);
```

Counting the above number of objects yields 3, which is true. But counting the following also results 3.

```
    "finance_fee_collection" =     {
    amount = "740.00";
    "due_date" = "2015-07-06";
    name = "third payment";
};
```

What I want is to count the number of "finance_fee_collection" items, such that the first one results 3 and the second one results 1. Is there anyway I can approach this goal?

Comment: Use the same structure for both cases. You have an array in the first example but no array in the second. Why?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know why. I use XMLDictionary to parse XML to NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one seems to be an array, the second a dictionary:

```
if([finance_fee_collection iskindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    count = 1;
} else {
    count = result.count;
}
```

something similar to this should work. :) hope it is helpful.

Comment: I just made a try and everything worked perfectly. Thanks alooot :)

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again, saved my life :D everything is working perfectly now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense really, since both `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` implement the `count` method, which should return 3 for both structures:

```
id obj = @[@1 ,@2, @3]; // This is an NSArray 

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[obj count]); // Outputs 3

obj = @{ @1:@1,
         @2:@2,
         @3:@3
       }; // now it's an NSDictionary

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[obj count]); // Outputs 3
```

Were you using `[object count]` to get the count?

Either way, I wouldn't assume that count would be 1 simply because the data structure is a dictionary (you didn't count it)

Comment: My purpose is to count the number of objects if its a an NSArray, and only return 1 if its an NSDictionary. So mt81's answer is what I wanted.  Thank you

Comment: (To clarify, calling 'count' on your dictionary returns 1 and calling 'count' on your array returns 3 ) I'm glad it solved it for you, but we need to have useful answers on the site for future users. Returning 1 is not the answer to a question called "Counting Objects in NSDictionary"; this is the reason for my contribution (it isn't a personal dig aimed at anyone)